# Need help with animated gradient

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

I am trying to get a nice gradient, but mine's a litte choppy. Maybe you can help me out with that. For a bette idea:

[image]

(from top to bottom: luminosity, expansion speed, radius)

[image]

---

### animation.tex

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {60,62,...,100} %Color should change from white into a strong yellow
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Radius{(\x-1)/41+3}
        \useasboundingbox[fill=black] (-10.2,-10.2) rectangle (10.2cm,10.2cm);
        \fill[fill=yellow!\x] (0,0) circle (\Radius); %Here in the first frame should be the brightest color (white) and then change into a strong yellow
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\foreach \x in {100,98,...,60} %Color should change from strong yellow into a strong orange
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Radius{(\x-1)/41+3}
        \useasboundingbox[fill=black] (-10.2,-10.2) rectangle (10.2cm,10.2cm);
        \fill[fill=yellow!\x] (0,0) circle (\Radius);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\foreach \x [count=\j] in {60,56,...,2} %Color should change into a light orange
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Radius{(\x-1)/41+3}
        \useasboundingbox[fill=black] (-10.2,-10.2) rectangle (10.2cm,10.2cm);
        \fill[fill=yellow!\x!orange] (0,0) circle (\Radius);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\foreach \x in {2,6,...,60} %Color should change into white
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
        \pgfmathsetmacro\Radius{(\x-1)/41+3}
        \useasboundingbox[fill=black] (-10.2,-10.2) rectangle (10.2cm,10.2cm);
        \fill[fill=yellow!\x] (0,0) circle (\Radius);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{document}
```

---

### main.tex

```
\documentclass[tikz]{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{center}
\animategraphics[controls,loop]{30}{animation}{}{}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this? (I focus on the graphics, seeing you have found a nice way to include the animation in beamer.)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \X in {0,2,...,358}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Radius{4-2*cos(\X+30)}
    \useasboundingbox[fill=black] (-10.2,-10.2) rectangle (10.2cm,10.2cm);
    \ifnum\X<91
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\OF{100*sin(\X)}
      \colorlet{mixyo}{yellow!\OF!white}
    \else
      \ifnum\X<271
         \pgfmathtruncatemacro\OF{50+50*sin(\X)}
         \colorlet{mixyo}{yellow!\OF!orange}
      \else
         \pgfmathtruncatemacro\OF{-100*sin(\X)}
         \colorlet{mixyo}{orange!\OF!white}
      \fi
    \fi
    \fill[fill=mixyo] (0,0) circle (\Radius); 
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great! Exactly what I wanted!